# how can i get these intent value in two different activities

Tags: android

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        int title = Integer.parseInt(marker.getTitle());
        Log.d("Result", String.valueOf(marker));
        //pass these value in two diffrent activities to update sqlite database
        Intent a = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Abc.class);
        a.putExtra("customer_id", title);
        startActivity(a);
}
```

Comment: You want to pass the customer id to two activities?

Comment: yes  one in service

Comment: which two different activities? You are starting one activity here, not two.

Comment: i want to pass data one in my abc actiivity and second one is in my service . plz help

Comment: then why you use only one intent? Use another intent to pass it to the service

Comment: set the result in `shared preferences` and access it wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create two `Intents` to do so.

```
Intent a = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Abc.class);
a.putExtra("customer_id", title);
startActivity(a);

Intent b = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, <service-name>.class);
b.putExtra("customer_id", title);
startService(b);
```

**In your Activity, access it as follows:**

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    int customerId = getIntent().getIntExtra("customer_id", 0);
    ...
 }
```

**In your Sevice access it as follows:**

```
 @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      final int customerId = intent.getIntExtra("customer_id",0);
      return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
  }
```

Comment: Or keep the value in some static instance and access it anywhere!

Comment: Its not a great Idea to do so because the static data will be around and won't be garbage collected. Moreover it will cause some complexity during debugging.

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) { 
//bundle.getString("customer_id")...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data you passed like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int value = intent.getIntExtra("customer_id", 0);
```

Where value will hold your customer id.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Abc.class);
intent.putExtra("customer_id", title);
startActivity(intent);

intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, <service-name>.class);
intent.putExtra("customer_id", title);
startService(intent);
```

Like this you can reuse one Intent variable to create two instance which you can use to pass your `customer_id` to abc and your service.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get values in two different activities first you have to put values in two different intents so you can get values in two activities.

for put values in Intent try :

```
Intent a = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Abc.class);
a.putExtra("customer_id", title);
startActivity(a);

Intent b = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Xyz.class);
b.putExtra("customer_id", title);
startActivity(b);
```

For get values from intent try :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) { 
//bundle.getString("customer_id")...
}
```